# PostgreSQL - Grouping specific columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

The similar problem might have been raised here before, but it's very hard to find the answer i'm looking for.

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
     isbn      |       Name 1             | Name 2       | Name 3     |  Date
---------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------+------------
 9998-01-101-9 | Duomenu bazes            | Tadas        | Onaitis    | 1995-12-31
 9998-01-101-9 | Duomenu bazes            | Jonas        | Onaitis    | 1994-02-28
 9998-01-101-9 | Duomenu bazes            | Petras       | Jonaitis   | 1995-05-30
 9998-01-102-7 | Programavimo kalbos      | Petras       | Jonaitis   | 1995-05-30
```

I want to `SELECT` this table so that For Each Distinct ISBN and Name 1 there would be the Minimum DATE.

This could easily be achieved by using the MIN() aggregate function.

And by knowing that the columns ISBN and Name 1 are equivalent, we could easily `GROUP BY` these columns, and `MIN(Date)`.

However, we have the columns Name 2 and Name 3, which are bound to Date.

And if we try to place them under the `GROUP BY` clause, they get checked while grouping, and we don't want that.

We want that Rows 1-3 would be One group, but they get separated, because Name 2 and Name 3 are making these rows distinct.

So how to make this so the Name 2 and Name 3 are not grouped, but instead bound to Date column and act as 1 column?

No new table creations or views aren't allowed.

Attempted solution: inner `SELECT` joining on Date from a different table, but this doesn't work if the Dates are duplicating.

Comment: Looks like a question related to OVER ( Partition by..) contructs available in Oracle

Comment: I could make use of a version for Sybase ASE 15.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) to get the row with earliest date for each combination isbn and name:

```
select distinct on (isbn, name_1) *
from your_table
order by isbn, name_1, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle

```
    Select isbn, name1, name2, name3,date,min(date)OVER (PARTITION BY isbn, name1)
```

Maybe there are similar constructs in other rdbms